# Issue of jquery.ui.datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

When using jquery.ui.datepicker,I got a empty div in my page.And it is not hidden. you can see what it looks like:

[image]

I use firebug inspect the code:

```
<div class="ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all" id="ui-datepicker-div"></div>
```

And I checked the css by firebug,it shold be hidden,the css is:

```
.ui-datepicker {
    display: none;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-left: 0.2em;
    padding-right: 0.2em;
    padding-top: 0.2em;
    width: 17em;
}
```

but this line:
**display:none** 
is strike-through. why this happen? How can I fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since CSS cascades, you must have some other instruction in your CSS that targets that DIV and is telling it that it must be displayed. Firebug will be able to tell you exactly which rule is overriding it, have a look

You should read this article on CSS specificity : http://htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/

**EDIT**

Example of how Firebug shows overridden classes. The ones that are not struck through is the active class : Here's the high quality image :  https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJoQv.jpg

[image: Example of how Firebug shows overridden classes. The ones that are not struck through is the active class]

Comment: "Firebug will be able to tell you exactly which rule is overriding it" how to do that? That's what I want. And I can't open that link.

Comment: The link works, copy paste and see. Added an image to show you how Firebug shows it.

Comment: Thanks,the image is sweet.Now the issue is fixed,I changed the order of css importing: jquery.ui.core.css should be before jquery.ui.datepicker.css.  And I have to use proxy to access that link because I am behind GFW. That article is very useful.

Comment: for me the issue was, that my css file url was linking to an older ui version. Setting the newest version in url fixed that.